# get value in an XML file with xmlStarlet tool

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xslt, xmlstarlet

My XML file structure

```
<properties>
    <structure name="preference">
        <structure name="cam">
            <property name="number" value="8"/>
            <property name="name" value="eddi"/>
        </structure>
    </structure>
</properties>
```

With XMLstarlet tool, I'm trying to get the value "**8**"  so I first tried this following command:

```
xmlstarlet -t -v '/properties/structure[@name="preference"]/structure[@name="cam"][property/@name="number"]/@value' file.xml
```

Then I get these errors:

> parser error : attributes construct error
>     xsl:value-of select="/properties/structure[@name="preference"]
>
> parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag value-of line 23
>     xsl:value-of select="/properties/structure[@name="preference"]

these errors are pointing to "preference".
I saw some topics dealing with this kind of action but their solution doesn't match with my case.

Do you have any idea on how to get this value?

Comment: I have updated your XML sample since it was not well-formed initially. Please update it further if it still does not represent your actual XML well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated (by @har07) and valid xml, e.g.:

```
<properties>
    <structure name="preference">
        <structure name="cam">
            <property name="number" value="8"/>
            <property name="name" value="eddi"/>
        </structure>
    </structure>
</properties>
```

(Note the self closing tags `/>`)

you could use:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//property[@name="number"]/@value' -v . -n file.xml
```

and prints

```
8
```

using:

```
xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.4, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.29, linked with 10129
```

Comment: @Siva my english is terrible, so ... i could only point you to the manual. :( :(

Comment: I tried your command and get only errors... : `parser error : attributes construct error
  <xsl:for-each select="//property[@name="number"]/@value">
                                          ^
parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag for-each line 23
  <xsl:for-each select="//property[@name="number"]/@value">
parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: template line 22 and for-each
  </xsl:for-each>
parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: stylesheet line 2 and template
</xsl:template>
parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: @Siva sry, can't help. For me (using the above xml file) prints `8`.

Comment: Well, I had 1.0 and now it's working with 1.2.1 on Redhat5, thank you!

Comment: @Siva yw, enjoy. :)